# Login to other website using cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to https://www.iwgac.com/ using PHP cURL and then retrieve the website's product prices. At first, I tried to make the login and then echo the home page to see if the prices are visible (the products prices are visible only after login).

It seems like the website isn't accepting the login (although the cookie.txt file changes). This is the code, based on other answer I found on stackoverflow:

```
class Curl {

    public $cookieJar = "";

    // Make sure the cookies.txt file is read/write permissions
    public function __construct($cookieJarFile = 'cookie.txt') {
        $this->cookieJar = $cookieJarFile;
    }

    function setup() {
        $header = array();
        $header[0]  = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[]   = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[]   = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[]   = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[]   = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[]   = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[]   = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookieJar);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookieJar);
        //curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    }

    function get($url) {
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();

        return $this->request();
    }

    function getAll($reg, $str) {
        preg_match_all($reg, $str, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    function postForm($url, $fields, $referer = '') {
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        return $this->request();
    }

    function getInfo($info) {
        $info = ($info == 'lasturl') ? curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) : curl_getinfo($this->curl, $info);
        return $info;
    }

    function request() {
        return curl_exec($this->curl);
    }
}

$curl = new Curl();

$url = "http://www.iwgac.com/index.php";
$fields = "form_name='main_login_form'&return_url='index.php'&user_login='**'&password='**'&remember_me='Y'&dispatch[auth.login]='Sign in'";

$html = $curl->postForm($url, $fields, $referer);
$html = curl_init();
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.iwgac.com');
$html = curl_exec($html);
echo $html;
```

Any ideas on fixing this issue?

Comment: Don't post your in-use password online.

Comment: It was created just to retrieve the prices, but thanks - edited.

Comment: Okay, just being safe. :) FWIW, your credentials are still in the edit history of this post, so if it *is* a security concern, you might want to change the password on the shop as well. Best.

Comment: btw might want to think of a better password.

Comment: No worries, changed already :)

Answer (score 1):

As always, basic:

1. Set `curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);`
2. Visit login page before submitting form

And advanced: use browser addon like HttpFox:

1. See the exact headers and post data submitted. There's often hidden values added by javascript to protect against what you are doing
2. See exact cookies. They can be assigned by files that are loaded after the page itself loads, and I doubt you request all the files included with curl.